# PostgreSQL query - find value in ANY clause or return true if list of ANY is empty

Tags: javascript, postgresql, conditional-statements

In my app I have a list that can be filtered by selecting `subcategory` badge. User is able to select a `badge` and show only the items from the particular subcategory. But I would like the app to display all items if no `subcategory` is selected. The list of selected subcategories is dynamic and injected into an SQL query (see the example below). But when the list is empty, then of course, query doesn't return any results. How to write a condition that if `ANY` list of items is `empty` then the query should return all elements of the table?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column = ANY( {{ $state.categoriesBadge.filter((item) => item.isSelected == true).map((item) => item.value) }})
```

Comment: `value` property of each selected subcategory **corresponds to a valid value in the column of the table.** Is my supposition correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [conditional expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CONDITIONAL) that notice the resulting array is empty and react accordingly: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/npAqn-Gt)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "table"
WHERE "column" = ANY(COALESCE(NULLIF({{ $state
                                      .categoriesBadge
                                      .filter((item) => item.isSelected == true)
                                      .map((item) => item.value) }}
                                   ,'{}'::text[] --empty text array
                                  )
                            ,ARRAY["column"]
                            )
                   )
```

If the array isn't empty, this is equal to what you already had; `nullif` and `coalesce` won't do anything.

If it's empty, `nullif` turns it into a `null` which in turn makes `coalesce` skip it and replace with the `column` value, resulting in a self-comparison `column=any(column)`.

---

Note that if the value of `column` is `null`, it will never match `any` and will never be returned - even if you specifically try to target it by supplying a `null` in the array. That's because `any` uses regular `=` comparison against every element of the array and `null=null` is `null`, not `true`.

To be able to search and match `null`, you'll need [`array_position() is not null`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE), which uses `is not distinct from` comparison instead: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2aBaeE5v)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "table"
WHERE array_position(COALESCE(NULLIF({{ $state
                                      .categoriesBadge
                                      .filter((item) => item.isSelected == true)
                                      .map((item) => item.value) }}
                                   ,'{}'::text[]
                                  )
                            ,ARRAY["column"]
                            )
                      ,"column"
                   ) is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query to achieve your desired result:

```js
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (
  {{ $state.categoriesBadge.filter((item) => item.isSelected == true).length > 0 ? 
    `column = ANY( ${$state.categoriesBadge.filter((item) => item.isSelected == true).map((item) => item.value)} )` :
    `1=1`
  }}
)
```

**Explanation of above snippet:**

1. Checking if the length of the filtered subcategories list is greater than 0.

   - If it is, we generate the `ANY` clause as before to filter the results by the selected subcategories.
   - If it is not, we generate a condition that is always true `(1=1)`, which will return all elements of the table.